# Is it possible to connect to the iTunes Connect database?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is it possible to connect to a read-only iTunes connect database so that I can get a live-time update of app sales? Furthermore, can I do this in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live updates aren't possible. Look at services like [appfigures.com](http://appfigures.com) and [several others](http://surgeworksmobile.com/iphone/itunes-connect-sales-reports-analytics-and-stats-tools-for-iphone-apps) that do these kind of updates. All of them read the daily reports from itunes connect. Not sure tho if they use an API or what they do exactly.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried the itunes connect app? Link is on the itunes connect front page at the bottom.

itunes connect doesn't have an API.

there are apps that download and analyze your weekly and daily reports. [AppSales-Mobile](https://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile) for example

On OS X [Appviz](https://appviz.com) works great

Comment: Good link with AppSales-Mobile. From their readme: "Because there is no real API to access iTunes Connect trend reports, AppSales Mobile scrapes itts.apple.com. This means that even small changes on this website can break AppSales’s ability to download reports automatically. In most cases, this is easy to fix and I’ll try to make a new version available asap."